# $\mathscr{N}(S^{n_{0}})=\mathscr{N}(S^{n_{0}+1})$ for some $n_{0}$ $\implies\mathscr{N}(S^{n_{0}})=\mathscr{N}(S^{n_{0}+k})$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

This is an exercise from Rudin.

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T\in \mathcal{B}(X)$ be a compact operator, and $\lambda\ne 0$.

I want to prove that $\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n_{0}})=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n_{0}+1})$ for some $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ $\implies\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n_{0}})=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n_{0}+k})$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

If this were for general $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then it would follow quite trivially via mathematical induction. However, I don't know how to proceed in this particular case.

It follows that the range of $T-\lambda I$ is the whole space and the dimension of the null space of $T-\lambda I$ is finite, but I don't think this is of much help.

Comment: You can prove $\mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^n) = \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1})$ for all $n \geqslant n_0$ by induction. Do you have an idea how you might go about that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, you'd prove it first for $n=n_{0}$, which holds by our assumption. Then you assume it holds for general $n\ge n_{0}$ and prove it for $n+1\ge n_{0}$. Thus I presume that means you have to show $\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n+1})=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n+2})$?

Comment: Right, and you use that $\mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1}) = \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^n)$ in that proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer I said $$\begin{aligned}\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n+1})&=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n}(T-\lambda I))\\&=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n})\cap\mathscr{N}(T-\lambda I)\\&=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n+1})\cap\mathscr{N}(T-\lambda I)\\&=\mathscr{N}((T-\lambda I)^{n+2})\end{aligned}$$, but I think that this is wrong. Namely from the second line on.

Comment: Yes, $\mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1})$ often is strictly greater than $\mathscr{N}(T - \lambda I) = \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^n) \cap \mathscr{N}(T - \lambda I)$ [the last equality holds for $n > 0$, typically not for $n = 0$]. You always have $\mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1}) \subset \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+2})$. So you need to show the other inclusion. Thus take an $x \in \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+2})$. How do you get something belonging to $\mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1})$ from $x$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Wouldn't you multiply $x$ by an element, say $y$, in $\mathscr{N}(T-\lambda I)$?

Comment: We have just a Banach space $X$, there's no multiplication defined for elements of $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, my bad! I blame it on the fact that I'm simultaneously doing some other work on Banach algebras. You would in fact apply the resolvent operator to $x$.

Comment: Not the resolvent. (If $T - \lambda I$ is invertible, the problem reduces to the fact that any composition of injective maps is injective, and thus becomes trivial.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I think there was a misunderstanding and a mistake on my part. By "resolvent", I actually meant the operator $T-\lambda I$ rather than its inverse (although I realise that it's the inverse we call the "resolvent").

Comment: Then yes, $(T - \lambda I) x \in \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1}) = \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^n)$, whence $(T - \lambda I)^{n+1} x = (T - \lambda I)^n((T - \lambda I)x) = 0$, i.e. $x\in \mathscr{N}((T - \lambda I)^{n+1})$, as desired.